# A link refer of data from PHP

Tags: php, html

I have create the list can show all the account.

Here is the php,i have show all the login account name.and how to get a href to their
only file .

example i get the account name call "admin",and then show on table .now i need to create 
a link on "admin" this word.so when i kick "admin" , i can see his profile in a new page.
and how to do it ?

(((((echo all account 's php)))))

```
$con1 = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","password");

  mysql_select_db("babytradeapps");

  $sql1 = "Select LoginID , Permission
          from loginacc where Permission = 2 ";


  $results = mysql_query($sql1,$con1);

  echo "<table border=5 cellpadding=10>";

  echo "<tr><th>members</th></tr>";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) { 

    echo "<td>$row[0]</td>";

  }

  echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the link in your `echo` statement:

```
echo "<td><a href='profile.php?id={$row['LoginID']}'>$row['LoginID']}</a></td>;
```

Answer (score 0):

- HINT: there is a plethora of tutorials on the internet that could
  help you understand.
- HINT: mysql_* functions are deprecated. Try MySQLi or PDO.
- HINT: if there isn't already, add an ID column to your database
  table.

What I outline here is the most basic of solutions to your problem, so that you may understand what needs to be done. **DON'T USE IT IN PRODUCTION.**

First we have to create a hyperlink to a PHP page that will pull out the user's data. [This assumes that the user's name is denoted by the 'LoginID' column.]

```
echo "<td><a href='userinfo.php?user=".$row['LoginID']."'>".$row['LoginID']."</a></td>";
```

Next, create a page called userinfo.php (for example), and `get` the value of the `user` key via PHP.

```
<?php
    $requestedUsername = $_GET['user'];
    /** Over here, you'll have to draw the user's data from the database for `echo`ing out later. 
        You can use something like: $query = "Select `email`, `address`, `phone` from `loginacc` where `LoginID` = '$requestedUsername'";
        However, as I stated in my hint above, please refrain from using mysql_* functions. They bite back. **/
    echo $requestedUsername;
?>
```

That's it!